# NSURLSession delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I wonder why my delegate method `-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location` not called. There is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self createSessionWithDelegate];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)createSessionWithDelegate {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/my-expected-image.jpg"]];
    [task resume];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
    if (downloadedImage){
        NSLog(@"Got image!");
    }

    // Perform UI changes in main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myImageView.image = downloadedImage;
    });
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
    NSLog(@"%f / %f", (double)totalBytesWritten, (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);    
}
```

Also I want to add, that my method : `-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite` works correctly (it shows output how much bytes I got).

Comment: Did you declare the delegate in the class such as `UIViewController <NSURLSessionDelegate>`?

Comment: @GavinWiggins declaration is: interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to implement

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

to see if some error is returned?

Comment: Im sorry. Problem was in bad link (in fact, link worked minutes ago and stop work after i try to implement delegate calls :)

Comment: FYI, if you create a session with **completion handler**, delegate methods will not be called.